# Viz chart not working

Tags: sapui5

I am using sap.viz library in my application, It is working of my laptop but when I uploaded it on the server I am getting below error I am unable to understand what's causing this error, as I did include 'sap.viz' in my index.html, any help to understand this will be highly appreciated

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: b._toInstance is not a function
at eval (http://ocsd051a.eu.unilever.com:8000/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zstandupreport/reso…ry-preload.json/sap/viz/ui5/controls/common/feeds/AnalysisObject.js:12:133)
at Array.map (native)
at Function.sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.AnalysisObject.toInstances (http://ocsd051a.eu.unilever.com:8000/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zstandupreport/reso…ry-preload.json/sap/viz/ui5/controls/common/feeds/AnalysisObject.js:12:101)
at f.sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem._toInstance (http://ocsd051a.eu.unilever.com:8000/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zstandupreport/reso…z/library-preload.json/sap/viz/ui5/controls/common/feeds/FeedItem.js:7:476)
at eval (http://ocsd051a.eu.unilever.com:8000/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zstandupreport/reso…/library-preload.json/sap/viz/ui5/controls/common/feeds/FeedItem.js:13:127)
at Array.map (native)
at Function.sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem.toInstances (http://ocsd051a.eu.unilever.com:8000/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zstandupreport/reso…z/library-preload.json/sap/viz/ui5/controls/common/feeds/FeedItem.js:13:95)
at Object.sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.helpers.VizControlsHelper.getFeedInstances (http://ocsd051a.eu.unilever.com:8000/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zstandupreport/reso…reload.json/sap/viz/ui5/controls/common/helpers/VizControlsHelper.js:7:140)
at d.sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame._updateVizFrame (http://ocsd051a.eu.unilever.com:8000/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zstandupreport/resources/sap/viz/library-preload.json/sap/viz/ui5/controls/VizFrame.js:28:245)
at d.sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame._createChildren (http://ocsd051a.eu.unilever.com:8000/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zstandupreport/resources/sap/viz/library-preload.json/sap/viz/ui5/controls/VizFrame.js:30:110)
(anonymous) @ AnalysisObject.js:12
sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.AnalysisObject.toInstances @ 
AnalysisObject.js:12
sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem._toInstance @ FeedItem.js:7
(anonymous) @ FeedItem.js:13
sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem.toInstances @ FeedItem.js:13
sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.helpers.VizControlsHelper.getFeedInstances @ 
VizControlsHelper.js:7
sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame._updateVizFrame @ VizFrame.js:28
sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame._createChildren @ VizFrame.js:30
sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.BaseControl._render @ BaseControl.js:15
sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.BaseControl.onAfterRendering @ BaseControl.js:10
a._callEventHandles @ sap-ui-core.js:144
a._handleEvent @ sap-ui-core.js:144
f @ sap-ui-core.js:144
R.flush @ sap-ui-core.js:144
R.render @ sap-ui-core.js:144
U.rerenderControl @ sap-ui-core.js:144
a.rerender @ sap-ui-core.js:144
U.rerender @ sap-ui-core.js:144
n.renderPendingUIUpdates @ sap-ui-core.js:144
(anonymous) @ sap-ui-core.js:135
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not providing 'feedPrimaryValues' correctly, Once that was rectified issue got resolved & now the graph is rendering as expected.